# implement an autocomplete-like feature when autocomplete attribute is off

Tags: javascript, html

I’m studying the implementation of autocomplete-like feature of [a page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english): typing a word in an `input` element, the system returns a list of options given the typed word.

[image]

According to the source code

```
<input autofocus="" aria-label="Search" type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" class="ft fon pr pt0 hbr-20 lc1 lp-10 lpl-15 cdo-search-input user-valid valid" id="searchword" [placeholder]="stateSearch.dataset_search" placeholder="Search English" on="input-debounced: AMP.setState({ stateSearch: { term: event.value, autocomplete: (stateSearch.dataset != 'wordlists' &amp;&amp; event.value.length) > 1 ? true : false } }), searchAutoComplete.changeToLayoutContainer(); tap: AMP.setState({ stateSearch: { autocomplete: stateSearch.dataset != 'wordlists' &amp;&amp; stateSearch.term.length > 1 } })">
```

The `autocomplete` attribute is off for `input` Tag. I guess `on` attribute is the key.

However, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) doesn't contain the attribute.

Why autocomplete attribute is off?

Is there a name for the autocomplete-like feature?

Is the attribute `on` of is `input` tag the key?

How do I implement the feature?

Comment: That `autocomplete = off` means browser will suggest possible completions for fields that the user has started typing in) or autofill previously typed data stored in browsers. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: The `autocomplete` you are talking about (in the picture) is live search feature from the database of matching words in the dictionary. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is jQuery library you can use to implement autocomplete feature like [this one](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: As say earlier `autocomplete` depend of the user, for example it will sugest the mail that he inserted multiple time on your site or other sites, before in a field "mail". If you you want to suggest values from a data set, calculated on the server side, you are searching for value list https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp.

Comment: In the site given as example the solution is a bit more complexe since it use a custom function at the input to calculated an display the sugested values https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that just using html attribute, main thing of autocomplete texts get from exist json kind of data or database of states, if you want to get states type it's letters, use autocomplete plugins

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/

Above link will help you for what you need now..